# Checking if JTextfield is empty after you have parseDouble or parseInt

Tags: java, user-interface, if-statement

I have several JTextfield which I have parsed:

```
double weedValue = Double.parseDouble(weedField.getText().trim());
int weedSAge = Integer.parseInt(weedSpreadAge.getText().trim());
```

The purpose of my GUI is to allow the user to input there own values to a farm simulation which displays movement of farmers.I want an if statement in my GUI which in the occurance of the user not inputting data in the JTextfield, then the default value for that field will be used. So far I have the following if statement:

```
 if (weedValue != 0){
                ModelConstants.setWEED_CREATION_PROB(weedValue);
            }
```

However, for my default values to be used for the weedValue variable, the user must input "0", however, I want it so that if the JTextfield is empty, the default values assigned will be used.

It doesn't like "" because I am comparing a String to a double, so how do I go about this?

Comment: Consider using a JSpinner instead

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
try
{
    double weedValue = Double.parseDouble(weedField.getText().trim());
}catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
   weedValue = defaultValue;//set default value here
}
```

Then just have another try catch block with same exception for your int.